# Making Blur Specific Area in CameraView with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, metal, metalkit

i have a side project that contains this screen below link. It is important that i want to create this screen in camera view, not in the picture.

I am thinking about dealing with Metal for this. how can i write this code, any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

https://gofile.io/?c=Wan0H9

Comment: This question is a bit broad. Have you looked at Apple's [AVCamFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcamfilter_applying_filters_to_a_capture_stream?language=objc) sample? It shows how to apply Core Image filters to a live camera feed. From there, it's just a matter of selecting the right filter chain (`CIMaskedVariableBlur` looks like a good choice here) to get the desired effect.

Comment: I think the impulse to keep everything on the GPU and leverage Metal is a good one. I think you may in fact need to use Metal to efficiently capture and display the video content. I just also happen to think that there are good existing high-level facilities (Core Image and MetalPerformanceShaders) that can make the tasks of filtering and compositing a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is going to work but if I were you I would create 4 different views (with semi transparent blur effect) as shown in the image below.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Good idea but how can i implement this idea in code with Metal? it is the hardest part.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 steps:
(i) first get complete blurred image from basic

```
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
```

(ii) With UIGraphicsContext, you can set blurred image as background image then crop original image and put over blurred image.

Then you can get resulted image from context.
Thats it.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i want to use it in live camera view, not image. Any suggestion?

Comment: yes, there is third party GpuimageView that support blur on camera with control on frame : (Y)